# How can I get Advanced Url Routing parametres?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, viewengine

It works now like **localhost/Controller/Action**
but I want it like **localhost/MainFolder/SubFolder/Controller/Action**

because I need to get my MainFolder and SubFolder name; like

```
RouteData routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
string currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
string currentMainFolder = routeData.GetRequiredString("mainFolder");
string currentSubFolder = routeData.GetRequiredString("subFolder");
```

MyViewEngine Codes;

```
    public class MyViewEngine: RazorViewEngine
{
    private static string[] NewViewFormats = new[] { "~/Views/MainFolder/SubFolder/{1}/{0}.cshtml" };

    public MyViewEngine()
    {
        base.ViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats.Union(NewViewFormats).ToArray();
    }
}
```

My RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Panel", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
    }
```

My Views Folder;

[image]

My Controllers Folder;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC Routes are not filesystem-based like old-style ASP.NET sites. All the controllers are registered at compile and the route just picks the one with the matching name. Where the controller lives on your filesystem is irrelevant.